# Spring Boot 3.1.5 - Failed to convert value of type java.lang.string to required type UserId

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am progressing on Wim Deblauwe book "Taming Thymeleaf" (page 314). I am using Spring Boot 3.1.5, SpringDataJPA mapping a MySQL database. While everything seem to work fine (no code warning in VSCode), I am now experiencing an issue with the record editing feature. When I click on the user edit link on the right of the user record list, I do not reach the user record screen and instead get a 500 error and a spring boot error: **Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mango.aquarius.user.UserId'**. See the attached screens and sample code below:

- User records list shows edit link user/19 when I hover on a user (Chrome bottom left corner)

[image: User list with edit link]

New button works (this matters as the edit form inherits from the create form):

[image: New button works => create form works]

Spring boot error is shown when edit link is clicked and leads to a short stack trace (see bottom of the screen in the terminal window):

[image: Spring boot error]

Leads to a whiteLabelerror page when the edit link is clicked:

[image: When edit link is clicked]

The code does not show any warning and Spring Boot displays an error only when I click on the edit link. I am using Maven and here is the pom.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mango</groupId>
    <artifactId>aquarius</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aquarius</name>
    <description>Aquarius Logics web site</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
         <!-- Dependencies -->
        <!-- <jpearl.version>2.0.0</jpearl.version> -->
        <guava.version>31.0.1-jre</guava.version>
        <javafaker.version>1.0.2</javafaker.version>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
        <!-- Maven plugins -->
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.8.0</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>v12.10.0</frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion>6.10.3</frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.1.3-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>${javafaker.version}</version>
        </dependency>
 
        <!-- Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
            <artifactId>alpinejs</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
                    <!-- <exclude>**/*.js</exclude> -->
                    <exclude>**/*.svg</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>install-frontend-tooling</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <nodeVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.nodeVersion}</nodeVersion>
                                <npmVersion>${frontend-maven-plugin.npmVersion}</npmVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>run-gulp-build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>gulp</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>build</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-gulp-build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>gulp</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>build --env production</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Since the error arises from a type conversion, I first accessed my database (MySQL) to check on the tab_users structure. It confirms that the primary key id is an integer: int(11) as expected.

- tab_users table structure

[image: Primary key is int(11) in MySQL]

Then I check the following code:

1 - User Entity: the entity declares the primary key as Integer

```
package com.mango.aquarius.user;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    //private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private UserName userName;
    
    @Column(name="gender", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender; 
    
    @Column(name="birthday", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthday;
    
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false)
    private Email email;

    @Column(name="phone_number", nullable = false)
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    // Hibernate requires a default constructor. We make it protected since our application
    // code shoud never use that constructor directly.

    protected User() {
    }

    public User(UserName userName,
                Gender gender,  
                LocalDate birthday, 
                Email email, 
                PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserName getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(UserName userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    
}
```

2 - UserController

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user.web;

import com.mango.aquarius.infrastructure.web.EditMode;
import com.mango.aquarius.infrastructure.validation.ValidationGroupSequence;
import com.mango.aquarius.user.Gender;
import com.mango.aquarius.user.User;
import com.mango.aquarius.user.UserId;
import com.mango.aquarius.user.UserNotFoundException;
import com.mango.aquarius.user.UserService;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.web.SortDefault;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService service;

    public UserController(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String index(Model model,
                        @SortDefault.SortDefaults({
                            @SortDefault("userName.lastName"),
                            @SortDefault("userName.firstName")}) Pageable pageable ) {

        model.addAttribute("users", service.getUsers(pageable));
        return "users/list";
    }

    // tag::create-get[]
    @GetMapping("/create")
    public String createUserForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new CreateUserFormData());
        model.addAttribute("genders", List.of(Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE));
        return "users/edit";
    }
    // end::create-get[]

    // tag::create-post[]
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String doCreateUser(@Validated(ValidationGroupSequence.class) @ModelAttribute("user") CreateUserFormData formData,
                               BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("genders", List.of(Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE));
            return "users/edit";
        }

        service.createUser(formData.toParameters());

        return "redirect:/users";
    }
    // end::create-post[]

    // tag::edit-get[]
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String editUserForm(@PathVariable("id") UserId id,
                               Model model) {
        User user = service.getUser(id)
                           .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id)); 
        model.addAttribute("user", EditUserFormData.fromUser(user)); 
        model.addAttribute("genders", List.of(Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE));
        model.addAttribute("editMode", EditMode.UPDATE); 
        return "users/edit"; 
    }
    // end::edit-get[]

    // tag::edit-post[]
    @PostMapping("/{id}")
    public String doEditUser(@PathVariable("id") UserId id,
                             @Validated(EditUserValidationGroupSequence.class) @ModelAttribute("user") EditUserFormData formData,
                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                             Model model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("genders", List.of(Gender.MALE, Gender.FEMALE));
            model.addAttribute("editMode", EditMode.UPDATE);
            return "users/edit";
        }

        service.editUser(id, formData.toParameters());

        return "redirect:/users";
    }
    // end::edit-post[]


}
```

3 - EditUserParameters

```
package com.mango.aquarius.user;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class EditUserParameters extends CreateUserParameters{

    public EditUserParameters(UserName userName, Gender gender, LocalDate birthday, Email email, PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        super(userName, gender, birthday, email, phoneNumber);
        
    }

    public void update(User user) {
        user.setUserName(getUserName());
        user.setGender(getGender());
        user.setBirthday(getBirthday());
        user.setEmail(getEmail());
        user.setPhoneNumber(getPhoneNumber());
    }
    
}
```

4 - EditUserFormData

```
package com.mango.aquarius.user.web;

import com.mango.aquarius.user.*;

public class EditUserFormData extends CreateUserFormData {

    private Integer id;
    // private String id;

    public static EditUserFormData fromUser(User user) { 
        
        EditUserFormData result = new EditUserFormData();
        // result.setId(user.getId().asString());
        result.setId(user.getId());
        result.setFirstName(user.getUserName().getFirstName());
        result.setLastName(user.getUserName().getLastName());
        result.setGender(user.getGender());
        result.setBirthday(user.getBirthday());
        result.setEmail(user.getEmail().asString());
        result.setPhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber().asString());

        return result;
    }

    public EditUserParameters toParameters() { 
        return new EditUserParameters(new UserName(getFirstName(), getLastName()),
                                      getGender(),
                                      getBirthday(),
                                      new Email(getEmail()),
                                      new PhoneNumber(getPhoneNumber()));
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // public String getId() {
    //     return id;
    // }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // public void setId(String id) {
    //     this.id = id;
    // }

    
}
```

5 - UserService

```
package com.mango.aquarius.user;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

public interface UserService {

    User createUser(CreateUserParameters parameters);
    User editUser(UserId id, EditUserParameters parameters);
    
    Page<User> getUsers(Pageable pageable);
    boolean userWithEmailExists(Email email);
    Optional<User> getUser(UserId id);
    
}
```

6 - UserService implementation

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository repository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public User createUser(CreateUserParameters parameters) {

        User user = new User(parameters.getUserName(),
                             parameters.getGender(),
                             parameters.getBirthday(),
                             parameters.getEmail(),
                             parameters.getPhoneNumber());

        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User editUser(UserId id, EditUserParameters parameters) {
        User user = repository.findById(id)
                              .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));

        parameters.update(user); 
        return user;
    }
    

    @Override
    public Page<User> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userWithEmailExists(Email email) {
        return repository.existsByEmail(email);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Optional<User> getUser(UserId id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
    
}
```

7 - UserId: here I created a value component for UserId to distinguish from a generic Id so as not to deal with the wrong Id value everywhere else in my code. Not sure whether this could be the cause of the problem...

```
package com.mango.aquarius.user;

public class UserId {

    protected UserId() {
    }
 
    public UserId(Integer id) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code samples instead of screenshots. Also stacktraces are very important when you request troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from a type conversion from String to Integer of the id variable used to retrieve a record for the purpose of Edit. Managed to resolve this issue in the following way:

1 - Create a StringToUserIdConverter.java component to handle the conversion from String to Integer:

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user.web;

import com.mango.aquarius.user.UserId;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StringToUserIdConverter implements Converter<String, UserId>  {

    @Override
    public UserId convert(String source) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(source);
        return new UserId(id);
    }
    
    
}
```

2 - Update UserRepository.java, by removing the line that declares a findById() method.

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user;

//import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


//@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository < User, Integer >, PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer > {
    
    // public Optional<User> findById(UserId id);
    boolean existsByEmail(Email email);
    
}
```

3 - Modify and complete UserId.java as follows:

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user;

public class UserId {

    private final Integer id;

    // protected UserId() {
    // }
 
    public UserId(Integer id) {
       this.id = id; 
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    
    
}
```

4 - Modify UserServiceImpl.java in the last @override statement at the bottom of the code as follows:

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository repository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public User createUser(CreateUserParameters parameters) {

        User user = new User(parameters.getUserName(),
                             parameters.getGender(),
                             parameters.getBirthday(),
                             parameters.getEmail(),
                             parameters.getPhoneNumber());

        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User editUser(UserId id, EditUserParameters parameters) {
        User user = repository.findById(id.getId())
                              .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(id));

        parameters.update(user); 
        return user;
    }
    

    @Override
    public Page<User> getUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userWithEmailExists(Email email) {
        return repository.existsByEmail(email);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Optional<User> getUser(UserId id) {
        return repository.findById(id.getId());
    }
    
}
```

There is no more error and any record can now be accessed by clicking the Edit link.

Finally, a new error pops up when you attempt to update the record. It is caused by a mismatch between the gender enum type declared in the entity and the gender type declared as VARCHAR(6) in the MySQL table. This problem is fixed by adding a column definition in the User.java entity component for gender, as follows:

```
    package com.mango.aquarius.user;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private UserName userName;
    
    @Column(name="gender", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(6)", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
    private Gender gender; 
    
    @Column(name="birthday", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthday;
    
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false)
    private Email email;

    @Column(name="phone_number", nullable = false)
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    // Hibernate requires a default constructor. We make it protected since our application
    // code shoud never use that constructor directly.

    protected User() {
    }

    public User(UserName userName,
                Gender gender,  
                LocalDate birthday, 
                Email email, 
                PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserName getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(UserName userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Email getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Email email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    
}
```

Now just upgraded to Spring Boot 3.2.0. All the above works fine.